# sapui5 sap.ui.unified.Calendar How can we remove the SpecialDate

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a small requirement in **sap.ui.unified.Calendar**, I want to remove the selected Special dates from Calendar. I'm trying with multiple options but still, I'm not able to achieve this.

[image]

On selection of a particular row, I'm going to call an OData Service and displaying the special dates which got highlighted in the Calendar.

**Here my requirement is like if I select the 2 or more records in the table I should not display the special dates and the selected dates should get removed and the calendar should display the dates without any selections**

I'm trying with **removeStyleClass** properties but it is not working. Here is my code.

```
if(sap.ui.getCore().roomsArr.length > 1){
                    MessageToast.show("Calendar Dates View will not get displayed for multiple record selections");
                    var oCal1 = that.getView().byId("myCalendar");
                    oCal1.removeStyleClass("sapUiCalItemType01");
                }
```

Here i guess like, if i get the selected row Id's then i can remove the style class that is getting violet Background. But im getting dynamic date values so im not able to achieve this. Can someone help me to fix the issue?

Thank you in advance